# capture scroll in inner div

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am trying to achieve is this, imagine you have a tall page with several divs in it.
The tall page itself is scrollable, the divs as well.

What I want to achieve is to prevent scrolling the whole page when scrolling the divs to the limit.
What now happens is that when you reach the end of the div by scrolling ferociously you start scrolling the entire page. I want to prevent scrolling the entire page, as this is for a private project and the items in the bottom rarely get used.

The divs are not generated dynamically so I can hardcode everything.

If it is possible I would really like to avoid using jQuery, cause that seems a bit overkill in this case.

//edit:
A small example can be found at http://gnur.nl/demo.html
The intended behavior of this demo is that the entire page never scrolls when you are scrolling inside the bacon div.

Comment: Can you present a demo? Without demo its difficult to analyze that what is happening?

Comment: This is normal behavior for divs with overflow:auto or overflow:scroll set, at least for desktop browsers. So you're obviously trying to do something more complex. But what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's a lost battle, the scroll event doesn't look to be cancelable:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-scroll

Or may be with a desperate hack to scroll back the amount of pixel that were scrolled:

```
var lastPos = isNaN(window.pageYOffset) ? 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop :
  window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function(ev){
  var diff = (isNaN(window.pageYOffset) ? 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop : 
    window.pageYOffset) - lastPos;
  window.scrollBy(0, -diff);
};
```

And using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` over the DIVs to prevent it or not.